# In RabbitMQ, how to handle the conflict between prefetch and 'redelivered'

Tags: rabbitmq, prefetch

Basically I have the similar issue as here:

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Consumer-crash-redelivery-and-prefetch-td34103.html

I want to prefetch some messages for performance. 
At the same time, if one message fails, I do want to give it a second chance (retry twice) and currently I use the 'redelivered' flag to implement this. If 'redelivered' is not set, I will re-queue the message, otherwise I will abandon the message.
This will cause a problem for those prefetched messages (not yet processed) if the consumer crashes as they have not been processed yet but the 'redelivered' flag will be set.

Is there any solution for this? Or any other better way to implement retry logic for the RabbitMQ message?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with this logic, one of which you've identified. First, the `redelivered` flag is a pretty useless field- it provides an indication of state for a stateless operation (processing a message should not require any "outside" information to be supplied). In general, your message processor should not care whether a message has been delivered 1, 10, or 100 times - the processing of the message and related behavior should not depend upon the number of times it was delivered.

The other issue, and this is more subtle, is that you have several different failure modes with differing effects, and you're finding that it's not a good idea to reduce all of these down to a single `redelivered` boolean.

There are a couple of things you can do:

First, you should make an attempt to distinguish between failures caused by malformed messages as opposed to those caused by a temporary condition with the server.  The former will never be able to be processed (and should be rejected outright), while the latter will potentially be able to be processed after the condition resolves. Right now, how do you decide between the two? How do you decide how long is long enough to wait before trying again?

Second, if you do need to understand prior failures, you can add a header to the message and re-publish (as opposed to doing a `basic.reject`).  The message will go to the back of the queue, but this state information will now be part of the message and available to future processors.

If this is a request-reply scenario, then just reject the message and make the client retry the request. Obviously this is not desirable if the client has no way of knowing when/if the message was processedd.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I like the 'add a header' and 're-publish' way. Also I have found I can NOT modify the header directly in the consumer callback function before I do a nack with re-enqueue (so that I do not need to "re-publish")? Seems to be read only to the consumer.

Comment: Also, regarding the different failures, right, if it's a message malform, I will discard the message. Otherwise I would like to implement some retry logics here. I need a placeholder to record how many times this message has been retried yet. Ideally for me that placeholder should be in the message (not my program)

Comment: You’re correct, a re-publish is different than a “nack” - the message cannot be modified in any way under the “nack” scenario. If number of times is important, I agree storing it with the message makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [dead letter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)?

Basically instead of re-queuing a failed message, you reject it.
And if you have a dead letter exchange configured you can setup a new flow for that rejected message, for example put it on another queue to which your process also subscribes to.

With such a mechanism, all messages will be processed at least twice, which seems to be your goal.